# Neo4j 2.0.0RC1 labels regression

Tags: neo4j, label

after importing my 2.0.0M06 Neo4j database to the new version 2.0.0RC1, it seem labels query doesn't work :

On 2.0.0RC1

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ start n=node(*) return count(*);            
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 246      |
+----------+
1 row
219 ms

219 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (c:contract) return c;                  
+---+
| c |
+---+
+---+
0 row
244 ms
```

On 2.0.0M06

```
neo4j-sh (root,0)$ start n=node(*) return count(n);
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 246      |
+----------+
1 row
1205 ms
neo4j-sh 

neo4j-sh (root,0)$ match (c:contract) return count(c);
+----------+
| count(c) |
+----------+
| 55       |
+----------+
1 row
```

193 ms

Labels is well in the DB, and when I look any node details I can see it.
But any request with labels filtering fails.

Comment: Maybe there's a typo? In your first example with RC1, you're returning `c`. In your second example with M06, you're returning `count(c)`.

Comment: Ok, I just installed RC1 and it also broke all of my label-based queries. Reverted to M06 and it worked fine. This looks like a bug.

Comment: Not bug, just no automatic upgrade between Milestones.

Answer (score 9):

As Peter says, upgrade is only supported between GA versions. However, there is a work-around for this specific upgrade. This only applies for upgrading a 2.0.0-M06 database to 2.0.0-RC1. It's not well tested, and you should make sure you have backup before you start. If you want to try it, here are the steps:

1. Cleanly shutdown on the old version on Neo4j (2.0.0-M06)

   ```
   $ bin/neo4j stop
   ```
2. Navigate to the database directory

   ```
   $ cd data/graph.db
   ```
3. Delete the label scan store (this is the critical part that has a new format). It will be recreated on startup.

   ```
   $ rm -rf schema/label
   ```
4. Start with the new version of Neo4j (2.0.0-RC1)

   ```
   $ bin/neo4j start
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this works over here:

```
➜  neo4j-community-2.0.0-RC1  bin/neo4j-shell         
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ create (n:contract);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Labels added: 1
505 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:contract) return n; 
+-----------+
| n         |
+-----------+
| Node[0]{} |
+-----------+
1 row
243 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

Since 2.0.0.M06, the store format has been changed, and there is no automatic upgrade between milestones (because they are milestones :). So, if you created the nodes in Neoj4 2.0.0.M06, parts of the upgrade may not work, which is probably the root of your problem.

Comment: Seems work only on new node(s) created, but not with theses imported from a 2.0.0M06 DB.